# Java - Reading a binary file and adding to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, binary

I've managed to learn how to read/write from/to a .txt file from an Arraylist in Java.  But I'm struggling to do so from binary.

The Arraylist would be in the format of:  String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String.

I was thinking of doing a .split() by the binary equivalent of a comma (00101100), but I'm completely stuck.  Can anyone tell me the basic imports needed to read a binary file and then add it to the Arraylist.  Thank you :)

*my idea might be completely wrong* so please suggest better methods :)

Lets call the Arraylist SD.  Just because that's how I've set it up.  Any more information please just comment!

Comment: Have you written a binary file?  Because it certainly wouldn't look like `00101100` in a text editor.

Comment: @JacobG I'm completely new to binary and that is why im asking for help!  It basically needs to read a binary file and it to an arraylist

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "from **binary**"?  Even `.txt` files are, in the end binary.  Do you have a specific "binary" format in mind, or were you just looking to learn something different?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I just got set it as an basic exercise and wanting to know more.  It just says: load and save all student details to file (in binary/text format).  The student details are categorised in the question as String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String  (That's how they are in the arraylist).

Comment: @KevinAnderson so from your higher understanding and opinion - what do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: @KevinAnderson it specify binary files, so I'm presuming a binary file has to be read and taken in and added to the arraylist.

Comment: In the meantime, possibly look into [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). This question looks related: [How do i read in binary data files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652944/how-do-i-read-in-binary-data-files-in-java)

Comment: The term "binary/text" could mean just about anything and therefore means nothing.  Unless your taskmaster has something more specific in mind, I'd say even a `.txt` file qualifies as "binary/text",  So I'd either seek clarification from whomever has set you this assignment, or find someone else who gives clearer assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.split(",");` to read the values. The binary text file you are talking about is just a regular text file, from your comment

> to file (in binary/text format).

Comment: Hi from the question: load and save all student details to file (in binary/text format), i.e. your system should
allow both binary AND text format files to be used.  Would this not be a .bin file or is a text file with binary numbers?